# Swift : UIAlertView button pressed action is not working

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I am a new IOS dev with little experience in Objective C, but now I am starting to learn swift instead.

I am making a test app with a bunch of different basic features just so I can get used to the language and I am running into some problems with AlertViews. I am trying to add functions to an AlertView (not AlertController). I have code for this and I am not getting any errors, but the function simply isn't running when I press the button in the Alert View. Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func Alert(sender: UIButton) {
    var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
    alertView.title = "Alert!"
    alertView.message = "Greg is Cool"
    alertView.delegate = self
    alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
    alertView.addButtonWithTitle("Okay")    
    alertView.show()    
}


func alert(alertView: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
    switch buttonIndex {

    default:
        if (alertView.tag == 1) {
        NameLabel.text = "I get it!"
        }
    }
}
```

I also am trying to find out how to make a TextField available in an AlertView. I do not have any code for this function though.

Please let me know if you have any Idea on how to get these features working. Thanks!

Comment: I plumbed up your IBAction and it worked fine for me.  Be sure to connected it to your button in the storyboard.

Comment: I conntected the Action in the storybaord because the Alert comes up, just the Action doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

1. You didn't set the tag of alertView. so `if (alertView.tag == 1)` will be false
2. You can set `alertViewStyle = PlainTextInput`, the it will have a Textfield

About alertViewStyle, check the document you will get:

```
enum UIAlertViewStyle : Int {
    case Default
    case SecureTextInput
    case PlainTextInput
    case LoginAndPasswordInput
}
```

So change as below, your code should work:

```
@IBAction func Alert(sender: UIButton) {
var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
alertView.title = "Alert!"
alertView.message = "Greg is Cool"
alertView.delegate = self
alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
alertView.addButtonWithTitle("Okay")


alertView.tag = 1
alertView.alertViewStyle = .PlainTextInput

alertView.show()

}

func alert(alertView: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {

switch buttonIndex {

default:
    if (alertView.tag == 1) {
    NameLabel.text = "I get it!"
}

}
}
```

Comment: How can I fix the first problem then to make the action work when I press the button? And that code is not working for me to get a textField... Where am I supposed to place that code?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I usually make is writing all the code, and placing the button, but **forgetting to connect the two**. Is the circle to the left of the code filled in, indicating that you have told the system which button ought to run that code?

Comment: I conntected the Action in the storybaord because the Alert comes up, just the Action doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

From the UIAlertView class:

`// UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of` UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
On iOS 8, you can do this:

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now UIAlertController is a single class for creating and interacting with what we knew as UIAlertViews and UIActionSheets on iOS 8.

Edit: To handle actions:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { action in
    switch action.style{
    case .Default:
        println("default")

    case .Cancel:
        println("cancel")

    case .Destructive:
        println("destructive")
    }
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you have used is pre-iOS 8. But I'll show you the way I do it regardless.

Add this function:

```
func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
    var title: NSString = alertView.buttonTitleAtIndex(buttonIndex)
    if title.isEqualToString("OK") {
        NameLabel.text = "I get it!"
    }
}
```

If you want to do it the modern way then this is the way to do it:

```
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "Greg is cool", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (ACTION :UIAlertAction!)in
        NameLabel.text = "I get it!"
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```